# How to save screenshot with Sikuli on Java

Tags: java, ui-automation, sikuli

I understand that screen.capture() should be used in order to take screenshot using Sikuli.
How can i save the image to a file?

Answer (score 2):

From the resulting `org.sikuli.script.ScreenImage` you can `getImage` that returns a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`. To save that to a file you can use `javax.imageio.ImageIO`:

```
ImageIO.write(screen.capture().getImage(), "jpg", new File("screen.jpg"));
```

Comment: The only thing I'd change however is the format. If you save it as jpeg, you won't be able to keep using it as a pattern because of the compression losses. png might be a better option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment because of reputation. Additionally, you can capture a specific region:

```
Region myRegion = new Region(0, 0, 250, 500);
ImageIO.write(screen.capture(myRegion).getImage(), "jpg", new File("screen.jpg"));
```

The region object would be defined according to your needs. In this case I created a simple region at x=0, y=0, width=250, height=500.